Firefox userChrome.css for Firefox 133
I recently upgraded to Firefox 133 and I have CSS customisation in userChrome.css for the search suggestion when you start typing in the URL bar to show bigger and in bold. This broke with the upgrade and when I use the browser toolbox and add the following to the Style Editor:
.urlbarView-results {
font-size: 32px !important;
   font-weight: bold !important;
}

I have the results I want. However, when the same code goes in userChrome.css and I restart Firefox, nothing happens. Could someone share some light?

Your CSS works for me. When you say that you enter the CSS in Style Editor, are you entering it as a live update in userChrome.css ({} Style Editor tab), or are you entering it in the style viewer of the Inspector tab? If you enter it in userChrome in Style Editor, there should be absolutely no difference to entering it in the file (assuming you're editing the correct profile). You should be able to go back to the Style Editor and see the changes there after the restart. (BTW, you don't need !important.)
